# How to delete last element in `times` loop

Tags: ruby

My code:

```
def counter(number)
  5.times do
    number += 1
    print number, " hello "
  end
end
counter(5)
```

Is it possible to to delete the last `hello` when I print this using a `times` loop so that the result would look like this?

```
# => 6 hello 7 hello 8 hello 9 hello 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to have numbers with the word 'hello' in between then you might consider a `Range` with `join`:

```
def counter(number)
  (0..number).to_a.join(' hello ')
end
```

You might want to change the `start` and `end` of the range:

```
def counter(number)
  (number..(number + 5)).to_a.join(' hello ')
end
```

Or you might use an Array:

```
def counter(number)
  Array.new(5) { |i| number + i }.join(' hello ')
end
```

Comment: Perhaps `def counter(first, last); (first..last).to_a.join(' hello ');end`. Then `puts counter(6, 10) #=> "6 hello 7 hello 8 hello 9 hello 10"`.

Comment: Thanks man, this definitely helps. How would I do this though, incrementing from the number passed into counter? With using one argument.

Answer (score 0):

not as the same you've written, but this also may be helpful

```
def counter(start, n=5) # n is optional 
  ary = (start..(start+n)).to_a
  ary.map {|i| print i == ary.last ?  i.to_s: i.to_s + " hello " }
  #you can change the i after question mark to i+1
end

2.2.0 :021 > counter(5) #will print 5 times, starts with 5
5 hello 6 hello 7 hello 8 hello 9 hello 10

2.2.0 :022 > counter(10, 5) # will print 5 times
10 hello 11 hello 12 hello 13 hello 14 hello 15

2.2.0 :028 > counter(3, n=7) # will print 7 times
3 hello 4 hello 5 hello 6 hello 7 hello 8 hello 9 hello 10

2.2.0 :029 > counter(3,7) #same as above
3 hello 4 hello 5 hello 6 hello 7 hello 8 hello 9 hello 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do...

```
def counter(number)
  5.times do |x|
    number += 1
    print number 
    print " hello " if x != 4 #conditional printing, only prints if not on last run
  end
end
counter(5)
```

That way you don't print "hello" if you're on the fifth run. Plus, this way is really similar to your original. Maybe it's a few more lines than the other responses, but it works fine and you don't need to use an array.

P.S. It's `if x != 4` because it's zero-based.